# Including (linux) bash commands

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I'm currently working on creating a simple Linux shell. I have a Shell class, with a vector I am treating as a sort of queue. The user could input something like

```
$                ls        -l   /
```

and the program would put this into my vector through a private method, with "ls" being at the 0th position, "/" in the 2nd position, you get the idea.  Then I go into my "interpretation" stage:

- First I check to make sure the user has put something into the prompt.
- Then it checks to see if the user typed in the word "exit", and if so it exits.
- If neither of these checks go off, the program forks. It then checks to make sure the fork didn't fail.
- **This is where I'm stumbling.** If the second to last character string in the queue is ">" we know that the last string is going to be a file that we need to create and/or open (and/or truncate?) and write the results of the command given by the user to said file.

  I need to do this using the bash command open and using flags, I cannot use c++ openers like ofstream. I then need to execute the input using the bash command exec.

Below is how my code has this written as of the submission of this post.

```
if (commandQueue.size() >= 3 && commandQueue.at(commandQueue.size() - 2) == ">") {
            //commandQueue.at(commandQueue.size() - 1) is fileName          open


            //commandQueue.at(0) is name of program to run                  exec
            //remaining substrings are args
};          //commandQueue.at(0) is name of program to run                  exec
// remaining substrings are args
```

How should I format these commands? fork was easy, it was just

```
pid_t pid = fork();
```

and a check. But I'm unsure as to how I'm supposed to open a file using flags, or how to format the exec command. I appreciate any help I receive, thank you.

Edit: I should probably put the second part of the if statement I provided in an else statement, or else return from the if statement.

Edit 2: I should probably mention I'm pretty new to bash commands, I've used a few of them before, but this is the first program I've written using them inside.

Edit 3 (reply to Galik):

Like, if you were using execve you'd have something like

```
    const char *path = "/bin/ls";
    char *const argv[] = { "/bin/ls", "/", NULL };
    execve(path, argv, environ);
```

(this is c code though, not c++) you see the "execve(path, argv, environ)"? That's what I'm curious about.

The man page for open has

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

but since I'm not using c, and I have my user's input stored as strings, I'm not sure how to deal with the const char*, or the flags or mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "format these commands"?

Comment: Like, if you were using execve you'd have something like 

        const char *path = "/bin/ls";
        char *const argv[] = { "/bin/ls", "/", NULL };
        execve(path, argv, environ);

(this is c code though, not c++) you see the "execve(path, argv, environ)"? That's what I'm curious about.

The man page for open has

       int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
       int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

but since I'm not using c, and I have my user's input stored as strings, I'm not sure how to deal with the const char*, or the flags or mode.

Comment: Oh god that looks horrible. Let me put it in the original post.

Comment: So all you're asking is how to execute a command with execve?

Comment: Too long; didn't read. Can you ask a smaller, more pointed example?

Comment: immibis: no, that was just an example in relation to Galiks original question, I'm asking how to pass in the strings I collect to a function like open or exec, not execve, inside of my c++ code. I'm sorry I'm really bad at asking these questions :'(

Comment: Jonathan Reinhart: If you look right below where I put in the first semi-large block of code, that's where the question really gets asked.

Comment: @ZachThompson There is no exec function. And open can only open *one* file per call - there is no way to pass multiple filenames to it.

Comment: I've made a relatively big edit to remove a lot of the unnecessary information. If you disagree, feel free to put it back - you get the final word on what goes in your post, even though other people are allowed to try and improve it.

Comment: @immibis I see now you're right. I'm looking at the exec(3) man page and it seems to be a family of functions. And I see that they eventually boil down to execve "under the hood" So yes, I guess I am asking how I should pass in what I have into the execve function. Since I'm not using a const char* like in edit 3. I don't even know if it's possible to have a const char* vector.

Comment: @immibis Oh wow that looks so much nicer. Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: @immibis umm... that's not quite what I meant. Unless that is what it is... it wouldn't just be execve(commandQueue.at(positionOfPath), ...at(positionOfArgs), ...at(positionOfCommand)

Comment: So you're asking how to convert a vector<string> into an array of const char *s?

Comment: What I've actually ended up doing is creating a cont char* arr[] and put the values in my queue in there using "commandQueue[i].c_str()" to convert them to const char* values.